# Zeppelin cannot be accessed from the internet

Tags: cassandra, apache-zeppelin, kaa

I installed Zeppelin in a AWS instance allowing ports 7080 and 7081 to be accessible from the internet, however when I try to access Zeppelin the web socket appears to be disconnected and I cannot proceed to create a new notebook. I confirmed the Zeppelin daemon is running and my access is set as anonymous. Can you please let me know what should I test to confirm if everything is working ok with the application? Is there a direct way to solve this issue?

Regards

Comment: Do you mean Zeppelin data analytics demo or just Apache Zeppelin? If it is only about Apache Zeppelin and hosting on AWS than remove tag kaa cause your question is not directly related to kaa application demo.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer, in this case I'm referring to Kaa data analytics demo